# Double Clicking on any DataGridView row in VB.NET to display the result in the form controls

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I didn't get the result I want from the following code:

```
    Private Sub tblView_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.oject, ByVal e as System.EventArgs)Handles tblView.SelectionChanged
        Dim st As String = tblView.SelectedRows.ToString
        txtID.Text = st(0)
        Try
           myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblRack WHERE RackID = "& txtID.Text &"", myConnection)
           myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
           While myReader.Read
               txtID.Text = myReader(0).ToString
               txtRack.Text = myReader(1).ToString
           End While
           myReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox (ex.Message)
        End Try
 End Sub
```

I wanted the data I selected on the datagridview row to be display in the textbox, but it displays the error message that st(0) produces "S" which is incompatible to my RackID data type. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the SelectdRows object to a string, which will probably return something `like "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection"`. Doing `st(0)` will take first charachter from this string, which is an 'S'.

Perhaps you should try this:

```
    Dim st As String = tblView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString
    txtID.Text = st
```

Comment: guy, it does not help. It display the error "identifier expected"

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn: That should not be caused by those 2 lines. On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I finally get the answer:
 

    Private Sub tblView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)Handles tblView.CellClick
         Dim i As Integer
         i = tblView.CurrentRow.Index
         txtID.Text = tblView.Item(0, i).Value
         txtRack.Text = tblView.Item(1, i).Value
    End Sub

I tested, and it works. Thanks guy...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
txtID.text = myReader.Item(0)
txtRack.text = myReader.Item(1)
```

or

```
txtID.text = myReader.Item("Fieldname1")
txtRack.text = myReader.Item("Fieldname2")
```